# Get users email addresses from active domain group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to send an email notification to users in an active domain group.  I can use `net group [groupname] /domain` to get a list of users, then `net user [username]` for user details.  But I can’t get the user email address by using `net user`.  Is there a way to do this via powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply install the [Active Directory module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx): We'll use `Get-ADGroupMember` to get the group's members, then use `Get-ADUser` to get any additional information required (in this case that's the email).

```
$ADGroup = "myGroup"
$ADServer = "myADServer"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$myGroupMembers = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($ADGroup)" -Server $ADServer)
Write-Host "Group: $($ADGroup)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
foreach ($myName in $myGroupMembers.Name)
{ 
    $myEmailAddr = Get-ADUser -Identity $myName -Server $ADServer -Properties mail | Select-Object -ExpandProperty mail
    Write-Host " $($myName) $($myEmailAddr)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial if you have the Active Directory PowerShell module installed:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory;
$Recipients = Get-ADGroupMember $GroupName | Get-AdUser -Properties mail | Select-Object -ExpandProperty mail;
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $ServerName -To $Recipients [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Active Directory PowerShell module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx).

In your case we can use `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet to retrieve group members, and `Get-ADUser` to retrieve additional details:

```
$GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember GroupName
foreach($Member in $GroupMember){
    $User = Get-ADUser $Member -Properties mail
    $EmailAddress = $User.Mail
    # Send mail to $EmailAddress here
}
```